# DSL, and SQL query very slow

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This question is both about Doctrine and Symfony2.
I've made a query using Doctrine DQL. And Doctrine generates an SQL like this;

```sql
SELECT f0_.id AS id0, f0_.nom AS nom1, f0_.prenom AS prenom2, f0_.email AS email3, p1_.move_distance AS move_distance4, a2_.adresse1 AS adresse15, a2_.adresse2 AS adresse26, p3_.nom AS nom7, v4_.nom AS nom8, v4_.url AS url9, v4_.cp AS cp10, v4_.insee AS insee11, v4_.lat AS lat12, v4_.lng AS lng13, COUNT(f0_.id) AS sclr17
FROM person_teacher p1_
INNER JOIN fos_user f0_ ON p1_.id = f0_.id
LEFT JOIN person_lesson p7_ ON f0_.id = p7_.person_id
LEFT JOIN lesson l6_ ON l6_.id = p7_.lesson_id AND (l6_.id = 1)
LEFT JOIN person_teacher_language p9_ ON p1_.id = p9_.personteacher_id
LEFT JOIN language l8_ ON l8_.id = p9_.language_id AND (l8_.id = 1)
LEFT JOIN note_value n10_ ON p1_.id = n10_.personTeacher_id
LEFT JOIN pays p3_ ON f0_.id_pays = p3_.id
LEFT JOIN note n5_ ON n10_.id_note = n5_.id
LEFT JOIN person_teacher_adresse p11_ ON p1_.id = p11_.personteacher_id
LEFT JOIN adresse a2_ ON a2_.id = p11_.adresse_id
LEFT JOIN ville v4_ ON a2_.id_ville = v4_.id
GROUP BY f0_.id LIMIT 2147483647 OFFSET 0;
```

The problem is about these joins:

```sql
LEFT JOIN person_lesson p7_ ON f0_.id = p7_.person_id
LEFT JOIN lesson l6_ ON l6_.id = p7_.lesson_id AND (l6_.id = 1)
LEFT JOIN person_teacher_language p9_ ON p1_.id = p9_.personteacher_id
LEFT JOIN language l8_ ON l8_.id = p9_.language_id AND (l8_.id = 1)
```

If I remove them, the request works. Long request, but works.
With the joins, the request is infinite (99.9% CPU time used by MySQL after 5mn) or maybe very long, but anyway, *far too long*.

How to optimize this query?

(PS : I thought the `AND (l6_.id = 1)` and the `AND (l8_.id = 1)` would act as "filters" and immediately remove unnecessary rows, but no, it makes things worse: it's faster if I remove those conditions, and add `where` clause at the end, something like: `WHERE (l6_.id = 1) AND (l8_.id = 1)`)

Here's my DQL code:

```sql
$retour = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select(array(
        'p.id',
        'p.nom',
        'p.prenom',
        'p.email',
        'p.moveDistance',
        'a.adresse1',
        'a.adresse2',
        'pn.nom as pays',
        'v.nom AS ville_nom',
        'v.url',
        'v.cp',
        'v.insee',
        'v.lat',
        'v.lng',
        'ROUND(' .
            $mul.' * ' .
            'ACOS( ' .
                'COS( RADIANS( '.$lat.')) * '.
                'COS( RADIANS( v.lat  )) * '.
                'COS( RADIANS( v.lng )-radians('.$lng.')) + '.
                'SIN( RADIANS( '.$lat.' )) * '.
                'SIN( RADIANS( v.lat )) ' .
            ')'.
        ',2) AS distance',
        ($in_kilometers?'\'km\'':'\'miles\'').' AS unit',
        'ROUND( AVG(n.importance), 1) AS importance',
        'COUNT(p.id) AS total'
    ))
    ->leftJoin('p.noteValues', 'nv')
    ->leftJoin('p.paysNaissance', 'pn')
    ->leftJoin('nv.note', 'n')
    ->leftJoin('p.adresses', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.ville', 'v');
/* (!) Optimizer: find out why if I do a join "ON"
 * it endlessly query. I did classical "join" then a "WHERE"
 * at the end. Find out why this method is faster:
 */
if ($lesson_id>0) {
    $retour = $retour
        ->leftJoin('p.lessons', 'le');
}
if ($language_id>0) {
    $retour = $retour
        ->leftJoin('p.languages', 'ln');
}
if (($lesson_id>0) && ($language_id>0)) {
    $retour = $retour
        ->where('le.id = :lesson_id')
        ->andWhere('ln.id = :language_id');
}
elseif ($lesson_id>0) {
    $retour = $retour
        ->where('le.id = :lesson_id');
}
elseif ($language_id>0) {
    $retour = $retour
        ->where('ln.id = :language_id');
}
$retour = $retour
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->having('distance>:dmin')
    ->andHaving('distance<=:dmax')
    ->addOrderBy($order_by_1, $order_sens_1)
    ->addOrderBy($order_by_2, $order_sens_2);

$params=array(
    'dmin' => $distance_min,
    'dmax' => $distance_max
);
if ($lesson_id>0) {
    $params['lesson_id']= $lesson_id;
}
if ($language_id>0) {
    $params['language_id']= $language_id;
}
$retour = $retour->setParameters($params);
$retour = $retour
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit );
return $retour;
```

Comment: Can you please show your original DQL query? Weren't you supposed to use `LEFT INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`? Why `LIMIT` is set to `2147483647`?

Comment: `LIMIT` is set to huge limit because sometimes i need this as a parameter, and sometimes and do not need any limit, so I set it to huge number. Moreover is you want to *always* use `OFFSET` (like I do), `LIMIT` becomes mandatory.

Comment: Can I ask why you use `AND (l6_.id = 1)` and `AND (l8_.id = 1)`? `language` and `lesson` will be empty if `id` is different from 1 but the query will still return the row. If you need this behavior, you should do it in the code otherwise in a `where` clause. How does the DQL query look like? Also you probably want to split your query in multiple queries.

Comment: There you go, I've updated with the full DQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to put the table with more rows after the FROM part of the select, 
and change the line 'LEFT JOIN lesson l6_ ON l6_.id = p7_.lesson_id AND (l6_.id = 1)' this way : It seems that you don't need to join with p7 because you force to be l6_.id=1, so I change to this

'LEFT JOIN lesson l6_ ON (l6_.id = 1)'

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Without a look at your MySQL table definitions, to speed up your query make sure you have defined an index on each column involved in a join, because otherwise mysql must evaluate each record of the tables that miss the index.

Please add more details to your question and I'll edit the answer to reflect the changes.